# How can I access a list if its name is stored as a string in a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

sorry if this post is bad as I'm new to coding and stackoverflow, apologies in advance :D

```
var list = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var listName = "list";
```

Can I somehow access the list via the variable to do something like -

```
console.log(listName[2]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally this isn't something we do in most modern programming languages. One way is to put your list in an object. Then you can use a string as a key in the object using bracket notation. What is the reason you want to do this? Maybe there is a better solution to your original problem that we can suggest.

Comment: `const lists = { list1 : [...], list2 : [...] }; const listName="list2"; console.log( lists[ listName ]);`